# python dictionary in a seperate file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a dictionary that's pretty long and I don't want to keep it in the same file as my program. I tried accessing the dictionary but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\....\OneDrive\Documents\python\atom\datesandtimes.py", line 22, in <module>
    elif whenever in get_close_matches(whenever, dict.keys()):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Is it possible to use it as a dictionary or to convert it or do I have to put the entire dictionary in the main file? My program is:

```
with open("dates.py") as files:
        dictionary = files.read()
        if whenever in files:
             print(dictionary[whenever])
        elif whenever in get_close_matches(whenever, dict.keys()):
             date = whenever in get_close_matches(whenever, dict.keys())
             print(dates[date])
```

I'm a beginner so if I'm asking a question that doesn't make sense pls tell me.

Comment: you called it `dictionary` to begin with and then used `dict.keys()`. Try `dictionary.keys()`. Your error is saying that `dict` is just a string and nothing more

Comment: There's a lot going on here, and probably more than one issue. I can't say for certain because you haven't posted the full program. Please make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clear things up.

Comment: Also, the fact that dict is a string is a problem: dict should be a class...

Comment: If the goal is just to store data in a separate file, I would recommend using [JSON](https://json.org), which is very similar to the way you'd write a Python dict. You can load a JSON file into a dict using [the `json` module, which is in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 4):

> `file1.py`

```
my_dict = {
    'key1': 'val1',
    'key2': 'val2',
    'keyn': 'valn',
}
```

> `file2.py`

```
from file1 import my_dict

print(my_dict['key1'])
```

Comment: This remark is unrelated to the quality of your answer and is more of a theoretical nature. I wonder how `import` in this context is better than The Evil `eval` or `exec`, considering that that's what is happening when a file is imported?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, you are trying to access your "dictionary" as file object. Whenever you access your file object with **read()** method. It gives you a string.

So dictionary = files.read() is a string. To convert that string into an actual dictionary object, you can use eval() a python inbuilt function.

```
dictionary = eval(files.read())
```

To verify if "whenever" key is present in your dictionary. Use,

```
if whenever in dictionary.keys():
    print(dictionary[whenever])
```

But according to your traceback results, I see an error at

```
elif whenever in get_close_matches(whenever, dict.keys()):
```

It says your "dict" object is String not a Dictionary. If dict is a dictionary used as string. You can use,

```
elif whenever in get_close_matches(whenever, eval(dict).keys()):
```

As explained above.

Comment: This is a bad use case for `eval`. (Actually, I would argue that a good use case for `eval` doesn't exist.) `ast.literal_eval` would be better, but better yet would be to either import the module (and let Python evaluate it) or else make a small modification and read the file as JSON instead.

Comment: Also, don't use `.keys()` just to check membership in a dictionary: prefer using the `in` operator directly, e.g. `if mykey in mydict`

Comment: @DanielPryden I agree, There is no good case of eval() if it changes the keys and values of dictionary during the process of evaluation. As post owner mentioned that he is a beginner. I felt to help him out with minimal changes to his code. But thanks for correcting me. :)